# Javascript: Difference between explicitly throwing an error object and not

Tags: javascript, error-handling, throw

In javascript, I have noticed two ways of throwing an error:

1)

```
throw "An error";
```

2)

```
throw new Error('An object error')
```

Is there any advantage of choosing one way over the other?
Is one considered a better practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Error` object has [nice little extras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Properties_2) like `error.name` and (in Firefox) `error.stack`.

If you need those, do throw an error explicitly. However, most people merely use the `error.toString()` method (often called implicitly). In the latter case it's overkill to create an Error object in the first place, so throwing a string works just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, JavaScript is implicitly throwing an Error object with "An error" as the message when you use method one. Unless you need to throw a different kind of exception (for example, one that has different properties explaining the error) method one is fine.

However, if you plan on throwing more complex exceptions in the future, you'll need to use method 2, as you'll need to define which object you're throwing.

**Basically, for this purpose both are equivalent. I'd go with method 2, since it will put you in the right mindset down the road ;)**